# Read date from ssh log with python

Tags: python, regex, date, ssh, compilation

I want to compare the date from each line with an given date.

```
# Example dump
cat /var/log/auth.log 
Mar  5 00:53:43 server012 sshd[15145]: Failed password for XX from X.X.X.X port 59113 ssh2
Mar  5 12:19:20 server012 sshd[17378]: Invalid user XX from X.X.X.X
Mar  5 12:19:20 server012 sshd[17378]: input_userauth_request: invalid user XX [preauth]
Mar  5 12:19:25 server012 sshd[17378]: Failed none for invalid user XX from X.X.X.X port 38485 ssh2
```

Python-Example:

```
givenvalue = datetime.strptime("2014-01-04 14:57:33", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dateFromLog = ....

if givenvalue > dateFromLog
   do something
```

I have no trouble to open the logfile and read each line one after another. 
My problem is the regex / compile command to read out the date (Example: *Mar  5 12:19:25*). Who can help me?

The next problem is the missing year into the logfile. So i can not compare the dates "correctly". My previous ideas are:

- read out the "last edited"-date from the logfile to get the (correct) year. *(Is that really failsafe?)*
- change the logfile format and add the year.

I have no idea to realize one of this both ideas. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any information about how to change the logging date format therefore i have maybe a new solution:

I write a small service / program which scans the original log.auth file in real-time (like [Code Sample: Part 5](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/).

When a new row appears: copy the line with year in a new log.file (like own_auth_with_year.log). 
I don't like this option: One more service to care. The solution is really inconvenient.

It could be so easy if you could change the time format...

**Update:** 
It is possible. Open the rsyslog.conf file (/etc/rsyslog.conf) and add your own template like

```
# My own a template
$template MySuperAwesomeTimestamps,"%timegenerated:1:10:date-rfc3339% %timegenerated:12:19:date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg%\n"
```

Now change the row (*auth,authpriv.*    /var/log/auth.log*) to

```
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log;MySuperAwesomeTimestamps
```

After that save your config, reboot the system (or reload the service) and check your new time format (*tail -f /var/log/auth.log*)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strptime` like this:

```
datetime.strptime(beginningOfLine, '%b %d %H:%M:%S')
```

This will create `datetime` objects of the year 1900 as the years is not given. You might want to adjust those yourself.

Example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('Mar  5 12:19:20', '%b %d %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(1900, 3, 5, 12, 19, 20)
```

Concerning your other question: The "last edited"-date is not necessarily in the same year as all entries from your log.

Comment: How to get the beginning of line? 
The problem with the year is furthermore unsolved..

Comment: @Matthias `beggingOfLine = line [:15]`.